# Unable to connect to database: Login failed for user 'sa'

Tags: centos7, jtds, jasperstarter

I am using `jtds jdbs driver (net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver)` to connect jasper with SQL Server 2000 SP2 but i always getting error `Unable to connect to database: Login failed for user 'sa'`. I am using centos7.

I have tried replacing several drivers with different versions but I always get the same error message.

This is my code:

```
java -jar /var/www/clients/client1/web73/web/vendor/cossou/jasperphp/src/JasperStarter/lib/jasperstarter.jar pr /var/www/clients/client1/web73/web/storage/app/uploads/presensi/report/report1.jrxml -f pdf -t generic -H 192.168.22.2 -u sa --db-driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --db-url jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.22.2:1433;instance=MYINSTANCE;databaseName=MYDB

Unable to connect to database: Login failed for user 'sa'
```

Comment: Can you connect using a sql client?

Comment: yes i can.. even I have built a template with ireport 5.6 using the same driver on my laptop